# Automatic script to update selected records in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am after some advice on how to produce a script that a user can run in QGIS. The script will be run against newly created feature/s (Point, Line or Polygon) that will perform not only a spatial join to populate the Ward, Parish and Postcode fields, but also populate a field called CREATED with the current date/time.

I haven't got a clue where to start to produce such a script, what platform to build it in on but i'm guessing that its possible?

All ideas welcomed.

Med

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QGIS: Running Scripts in the Python Console](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/27/qgis-running-scripts-in-the-python-console/) by Gary Sherman should be a good starting point. Continue to the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, just what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: URL of the cookbook is http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/